# Selenium Webdriver: finding checkbox based on multiple row values

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, webdriver

I went through this site but could not find a solution for my problem and was wondering if people with more experience in Selenium could help me out.
Apologies for the long post, but I wanted to make sure that I explained things properly.

I am using Java. I normally use Rational Function Tester (Java) but I am trying to see if I can rewrite the code from some of the tests, to see how easy it would be to convert.

I have a table with 11 columns and 4 rows (but it could be 20 or 50 rows, it fluctuates during testing).
I can read the table and its content to find the row that I want. I compare each of the first 10 cell values and, if they all match, I want to click on the checkbox that is in column 11. Otherwise, continue to the next row.

The function works properly to retrieve the values from each cell. However, when I try to click on the checkbox, it is always selecting the one that is on the first row.
When I checked the attributes, I can see that all the checkboxes have the same 'name' but a different value (such as 1330361, 1330363, 1330359, etc.).
Interestingly, if I do a search for all the check boxes in the row, it reports 4 of them (the number found in the whole table, not on the row).

I am probably making a very basic mistake but I cannot figure out what it is.

I use the following code to search in the table. The function receives the table row and, at this point, I am just reporting the cell values then attempt to click on the checkbox that is in the row. It is kind of a debugging function.
I am not sure if it is proper to post a huge amount of code, so I will just put a short version of it, where I try to click on each of the checkbox in the table.

```
// Passing a specific table row to the function:
List<WebElement> columns=myRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
for (int iLoop = 0;iLoop < columns.size();iLoop++)
{
     System.out.println("Column " + iLoop + " : '" + columns.get(iLoop).getText().toString() + "'");
     // code to compare actual and expected values and setting of a boolean variable.

     if (iLoop == 10 && recordMatch)
     {
          tCheckbox = myRow.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
         System.out.println("Value is :" + tCheckbox.getAttribute("value").toString());
          tCheckbox.click();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The XPath to get the checkbox has the whole page as scope. I would add a dot in front to get a scope relative to the element:

```
// Passing a specific table row to the function:
List<WebElement> columns=myRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
for (int iLoop = 0;iLoop < columns.size();iLoop++)
{
  System.out.println("Column " + iLoop + " : '" + columns.get(iLoop).getText().toString() + "'");
  // code to compare actual and expected values and setting of a boolean variable.

  if (iLoop == 10 && recordMatch)
  {
    tCheckbox = myRow.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='checkbox']"));
    System.out.println("Value is :" + tCheckbox.getAttribute("value").toString());
    tCheckbox.click();
  }
}
```

But a better way would be to gather all the checkboxes before iterating the columns:

```
// Passing a specific table row to the function:
List<WebElement> columns=myRow.findElements(By.xpath("//td[.//input[@type='checkbox']]"));
List<WebElement> checkboxes=myRow.findElements(By.xpath("//td//input[@type='checkbox']"));
for (int iLoop = 0;iLoop < columns.size();iLoop++)
{
  System.out.println("Column " + iLoop + " : '" + columns.get(iLoop).getText().toString() + "'");
  // code to compare actual and expected values and setting of a boolean variable.

  if (iLoop == 10 && recordMatch)
  {
    tCheckbox = checkboxes.get(iLoop);
    System.out.println("Value is :" + tCheckbox.getAttribute("value").toString());
    tCheckbox.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Florent,

Wow! That worked great. I thank you so much.

I guess that I really need to work on the xpath knowledge. For some reason, it is just no sinking in. I am so used to working with RFT.

Andre

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Click check box based on values, you have to list all values using a for loop and Check box absolute xpath and pass "i"  value, 
See code below:

```
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id ='content']/table"));
        /*List <WebElement> head = driver.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
        head.size();

        for (int h=0;h<head.size();h++){*/
        List <WebElement> row = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        row.size();


        for (int i=0;i<row.size();i++){



            List <WebElement> col = row.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            col.size();


            for (int j=0;j<col.size();j++){
                String cv = col.get(j).getText();
// If name is Saudi Arabia, it will click on check box 
                if(cv.equalsIgnoreCase("Saudi Arabia")){
// Divide the x path where colunm is changing html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[pass i value]/td[6]";
                    String xp1 = "html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[";
                    String xp2 = "]/td[6]";

// Pass the i value xp1+i+xp2
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp1+i+xp2)).click();
                }
                System.out.println(cv);
            }




        }
```